# Dynamics Crm plugin add followers to a contact

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How can I add a follower to a Contact, using a plugin? I would like to get the same result as when I click the button "Follow" in the Contact form, but make other users follow the contact.

I need to accomplish this, because when I merge two Contacts, the "master" contact does not have the other contact's followers. Maybe I can change this behavior in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a PostFollow request

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547438.aspx